# Read multiple parquet files as dict of dicts or dict of lists

Tags: pyspark

I have a large dataframe stored in multiple .parquet files.

I would like to loop trhough each parquet file and create a dict of dicts or dict of lists from the files.

I tried:

```
l = glob(os.path.join(path,'*.parquet'))

list_year = {}
for i in range(len(l))[:5]:
    a=spark.read.parquet(l[i])
    list_year[i] = a
```

however this just stores the separate dataframes instead of creating a dict of dicts

Comment: have you tried `spark_df.asDict()` to convert to dictionary?

Comment: I got the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Comment: Not `.to_dict` try with `.asDict()`

Comment: still gives me AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'asDict'

Comment: Share full traceback error log in your question